# .Net O/R mapper with support for database-first with msaccess databases

Tags: .net, ms-access, orm

I'm looking for a .Net O/R mapper framework that supports the database-first approach with Microsoft Access databases. Does such a thing even exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is a MS Access provider for Entity Framework

https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/

And EF supports Database-first approach

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the *DataTableAdapters* that comes with *Visual Studio*.

Not as sophisticated as EF but very operative, indeed for smaller and medium scale projects.